# Best solution for SQL Task

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Task:**

There is table EmployeesInfo with columns: EmplId, EmplName, EmplCar, ChiefId
Task: select only employees who have chief assigned, assigned chief must have a car and should have at least three direct subordinates (direct subordinate for Chief is an employee who has chief emplID in his ChiefID column).

Output columns: EmplId, EmplName, ChiefId, ChiefCar, Subordinate count

**Note:** Chief is also an employee with ChiefId = NULL.

**Question:**
What is the best solution for this task? I have one but i think it's too monstrous.

**Additions:** Im using SQL Server. It will be extremely good if you will use it to solve this task. Thank you.

**My solution:**

```
SELECT E.EmpId, E.EmpName, E.ChiefId, B.EmpCar AS [Chief Car]
,
(SELECT COUNT(EE.EmpId) FROM EmployeeInfo AS EE
 INNER JOIN EmployeeInfo BB ON EE.ChiefId = BB.EmpId WHERE EE.ChiefId = E.ChiefId AND E.ChiefId IN
    (
        SELECT BB.EmpId
        FROM EmployeeInfo AS BB
        INNER JOIN EmployeeInfo AS EE
        ON BB.EmpId = EE.ChiefId
        GROUP BY BB.EmpId
        HAVING COUNT(EE.EmpId) >= 3
    )
) 
AS [Subordinate Count]

FROM EmployeeInfo AS B
LEFT JOIN EmployeeInfo AS E
ON E.ChiefId = B.EmpId
WHERE B.EmpCar IS NOT NULL AND E.ChiefId IN 
(
    SELECT B2.EmpId
    FROM EmployeeInfo AS B2
    INNER JOIN EmployeeInfo AS E2
    ON B2.EmpId = E2.ChiefId
    GROUP BY B2.EmpId
    HAVING COUNT(E2.EmpId) >= 3
);
```

**Some data:**

followed by EmpId, EmpName, EmpCar, ChiefId

1, Emp1,   NULL,      4

2, Emp2,   NULL,      4

3, Emp3,   NULL,      4

4, Chief1, Somecar1, NULL

5, Emp4, NULL, 7

6, Emp5, NULL, 7

7, Chief2, Somecar2, NULL

**Desired results:**

followed by EmpId, EmpName, ChiefId, ChiefCar, Subordinate count

1, Emp1, 4, Somecar1, 3

2, Emp2, 4, Somecar1, 3

3, Emp3, 4, Somecar1, 3

Comment: post your solution first, so we can see what have you tried.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for teh codez.

Comment: @CiucaS just added my solution

Comment: I can't follow this QUERY , can you post some data and the desire output?

Comment: @CiucaS added some, hope it helps

Comment: @shree.pat18 added my solution to question, hope now it will not be off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible solution:

```
SELECT E.EmpId, E.EmpName, B.EmpId AS [Chief Id], B.EmpCar AS [Chief Car], 
(SELECT COUNT(EmpId) FROM Employees WHERE ChiefId = B.EmpId) AS [Subordinate Count]
FROM Employees AS E
INNER JOIN Employees AS B
ON E.ChiefId = B.EmpId
WHERE 3 <= (SELECT COUNT(EmpId) FROM Employees WHERE ChiefId = B.EmpId)
AND B.EmpCar IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below could help you, its in SQL:-

```
SELECT distinct x.Employeeinfo from EmployeeInfo x, EmployeeInfo y
where y.CheflID IN (Select y.CheflID from EmployeeInfo y)
and x.CheflId=y.CheflID;
```

Hope you got what you were seaching for...